# How do i persist the login token on IOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Im using Alamofire to do the HTTP methods on the IOS/Swift side and while on the server-side I'm using token based authentication using node.js/Express.

Here's the scenario, User clicks login and then it will use Alamofire to call the 
`/auth/login` url to do the logic, then the server will response with a token, then it will navigate the user to the main screen. Everything is working smoothly.

I used Keychain to store the token. https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://specialapp.herokuapp.com/auth/login", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
            .responseJSON { response in
                if let httpError = response.result.error {
                    let statusCode = httpError.code
                    print(statusCode)
                } else {
                    if let value = response.result.value {
                        let json = JSON(value)
                        let statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)!
                        if statusCode == 401 {
                            print(json)
                        } else {
                            print(json["token"])
                            let token = json["token"]
                            self.keychain["token"] = String(token)
                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Main", sender: sender)
                        }
                    }


                }

            }
```

But the real problem lies when I close the application, and then reopen it again. What I want to achieve is whenever a user login, close the application and reopen it again will bring the user back to main screen.

How would I achieve that?

Comment: ever found the answer for this?

Answer (score 4):

In viewdidload method you can check your token like this. If it is not set it means still login is not done.

```
if let token =   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(KToken) as? NSString {
       // Token stored in NSUserDefaults.
} else {
       // Have to login
}
```

And store value in NSUserDefault like this.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(email, forKey: KToken)

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Answer (score 2):

Update:

The application state can be stored with some `ID` for particular screen. In `-viewDidLoad()` take the previous `ID` from `NSUserDefaults` and have a local variable. then set the current pages `ID` in `NSUserDefaults`. Vice versa in `-dealloc()` remove the current ID an store the previous ID.

When you have Super View controller for all of your `viewcontroller` the effort is too less

Store your whatever token in `keychain`. The data that are stored in keychain won't get deleted by itself even after the app is deleted. Find the best [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459879/how-to-store-a-string-in-keychain-ios)

you have an other option to store keychain and application state in `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I forgot to mention that I did use keychain https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess

Comment: I managed to store the token, but do I need to do some logic upon the initial view controller?

Comment: So I could understand the Question is about application state, not about persisting data.

Comment: Can i put the id in keychain? or it has to be in NSUserdefaults?

Comment: Application state can be in user defaults. So that when app deleted app state would also be deleted